# /etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory (but it exists!)

Tags: wifi

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and all of the sudden I have no wifi (or wired) internet.

When I do `cat /etc/resolv.conf` I get:

```
/etc/resolv.conf no such file or directory
```

but its there when I do `ls -la /etc/res*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 13 2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

what is going on and how do I get wifi/internet to work again?

Comment: Try "sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf". Your /etc/resolv.conf is a link to another file or directory that you may not have read permissions for as a regular user.

Comment: Does `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` exist?

Comment: Split the problem. "_have no wifi (or wired) internet_" - try `ping -c3 1.1.1.1`. If you get a response then you have Internet access but no name resolution and we can address that. If you don't get a response then you need to address that first